# Washing skin under nails in wudu

Tags: wudu, taharah, ghusl, hanafi

Salam.I am a follower of Imam Abu Hanifa. Does skin under/beneath the nails be washed in wudu and ghusul? If yes, then how? Should we hold our hands vertically under the tap? I ask this because I take more time than a normal person in wudu.

Answer (score -1):

Assalamu Aleikum

Our religion of Islam is one of moderation

"Thus We have appointed you a middle nation, that ye may be witnesses against mankind, and that the messenger may be a witness against you. And We appointed the qiblah which ye formerly observed only that We might know him who followeth the messenger, from him who turneth on his heels. In truth it was a hard (test) save for those whom Allah guided. But it was not Allah's purpose that your faith should be in vain, for Allah is Full of Pity, Merciful toward mankind." --- Quran -- 2:143 (Sura Baqarah, The Cow)

Islam is a religion of simplicity and gentleness. One is not required to punish themselves  or go to extremes in fulfilling their religious obligations. Just make a normal ablution and use water sparingly. Use a wudhu bottle if you can to minimize the water that goes to waste. Follow the example of the Prophet Muhammad (salawaatulahi Rabi Wasalaamu Aleyhi) and his blessed companions.